# Handling json vars from php and jQuery giving a text var instead

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Im receiving a text from a php script over ajax using jquery like this:

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
           url: 'someURL.com',
                success:function(result){
                    json = JSON.parse(result.rgraph);
})
```

The result.rgraph is sended in php as:

```
$arr = array( 'actiondata'=> 'some info here',  'rgraph' => $this->_rgraph() );
$jsonTable = json_encode($arr);

return $jsonTable;
```

Where $this->_rgraph() is just a function that returns:

> return '{ id: "0_0", name: "Categorie", children: [{ id: "0_1", name: "Business services", data: { relation: "" },children: [{ id: "0_2", name: "H-FARM Ventures", data: { relation: "" }, children: [] }]},{ id: "0_3", name: "Cause", data: { relation: "" },children: [{ id: "0_4", name: "StartupVisa", data: { relation: "" }, children: [] }]},{ id: "0_5", name: "Community", data: { relation: "" },children: [{ id: "0_6", name: "Different Solutions", data: { relation: "" }, children: [] }]},{ id: "0_7", name: "News/media website", data: { relation: "" },children: [{ id: "0_8", name: "iSpazio", data: { relation: "" }, children: [] }]},{ id: "0_9", name: "Non-profit organization", data: { relation: "" },children: [{ id: "0_10", name: "Indigeni Digitali", data: { relation: "" }, children: [] }]},{ id: "0_11", name: "Website", data: { relation: "" },children: [{ id: "0_12", name: "Hot Pin Venezuela", data: { relation: "" }, children: [] },{ id: "0_13", name: "El Chiguire Bipolar", data: { relation: "" }, children: [] }]}], data: { relation: "some text" }}';

I then use this var (json) in a chart engine, the think is, if i copy the string returned by _rhraph() over the ajax hardcoding it on the javascript it works, it gets the string as an object and draw the chard. But if a let the script retrieve the var from the php script as you may suppose this var arrives as text on **json = JSON.parse(result.rgraph);** because if i do an alert on json i see the content and not Object object. So at this point I changed the code to: `json = JSON.parse(result.rgraph);`

But this gives me an error: *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token i*. I have no idea what is going on, seems like the json var is not correctly formatted but why when I hardcode the var it works? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote your keys for valid JSON

Answer (score 1):

That's not valid JSON. key names must be quoted, e.g:

```
{ "id" : ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put all JSON keys in quotes ("id", "etc")...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to parse it with `jQuery.parseJSON()`:

```
json = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
```